# Apache Spark: Convert column with a JSON String to new Dataframe in Scala spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with a column of string type, this string is a JSON format, I wanted to convert this column to multiple columns based on this JSON format. I can do it if I have the JSON schema, but I don't have it.

**Example**:

Original Dataframe:

```
---------------------
|        json_string|
---------------------
|{"a":2,"b":"hello"}|
|   {"a":1,"b":"hi"}|
---------------------
```

After Conversion/Parse

```
--------------
|  a |     b |
--------------
|  2 |  hello|
|  1 |     hi|
--------------
```

I using Apache Spark 2.1.1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you do not have a predefined schema the other option is to convert it to `RDD[String]` or `Dataset[String]` and load as a `json`

Here is how you can do

```
//convert to RDD[String]
val rdd = originalDF.rdd.map(_.getString(0))

val ds = rdd.toDS
```

Now load as a json

```
val df = spark.read.json(rdd) // or spark.read.json(ds)

df.show(false)
```

Also use `json(ds)`, `json(rdd)` is deprecated from `2.2.0`

> @deprecated("Use json(Dataset[String]) instead.", "2.2.0")

Output:

```
+---+-----+
|a  |b    |
+---+-----+
|2  |hello|
|1  |hi   |
+---+-----+
```